# Downloading route details from google map

Tags: iphone, google-maps, dictionary, mapkit

I want to draw a route in google map with desites A & B  directions
specidied,I am able to do this through google directs ,thanks to
goole..No i want to create a static map with only that route and hence
i need to get all the latitude and longitude details into CSV for 100M
distance of this route.

Is there any possible way as currently i need to place a marker at
every distance and copy the co-ordinates manually from map which is
very tedious when i need to do this from 100KM + ,

Any help provided is truely appreciated.

Comment: If I can clarify my answer, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the directions via the [Javascript directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/), the following can all be done programmatically, but I am assuming you are getting your directions from the [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com) page? If so then you can get the KML associated with the directions response via My Maps.

After you make your directions request you need to go to the bottom of the text directions and select *Save to My Maps*.  This will add the directions to your *My Maps* page (assuming you are logged into a google account).  Go to *My Maps* and select the entry you just added. Click the *edit* button on the left.  This will expose a *View in Google Earth* link on the top right of the map.  Clicking this link will download a file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<name>Directions to Scone, NSW</name>
<description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <NetworkLink>
    <name>Directions to Scone, NSW</name>
    <Link>
    <href>http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;vps=1&amp;jsv=262a&amp;oe=UTF8&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=109115301202341389527.00048cf92603b4141b1cf&amp;output=kml</href>
    </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Replace all the escaped `&amp;` with `&` in the URL in the href element and request the URL in the browser. This will give you the [KML](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&vps=1&jsv=262a&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=109115301202341389527.00048cf92603b4141b1cf&output=kml) that you are after:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&vps=1&jsv=262a&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=109115301202341389527.00048cf92603b4141b1cf&output=kml
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Cannonade. I got the codes similar to above. But when I replaced $amp with & in the browser, I didnt got the csv file.  Can you please give me some further help ?

Comment: @iSharreth You might have missed one.  See my edit above, I have included a link to the KML based on my request.  N.B. You wont get a CSV file from this link, you will get a KML file (XML) with the raw location data it in. You will need to do some processing on that file to strip out everything except the latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: @iSharreth Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can be helpful but if you are using googles rest service to get the data have  a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/95842/Consuming-Google-Maps-API-Rest-Services-in-NET.aspx).